# How do I automate build and testing for an asp.net ajax application in Team Foundation Server?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, tfs, msbuild, build-automation

> **Q.** We're looking for a way to *automate
>   build process*, run *test cases* and
>   store build results.

A problem could be raise as the application on which we want to setup this process is an ajax application -- a one page operation application highly rely on JavaScript. The QA team is using QTP to automate their testing.

> **Q.** Now as we're moved to *Team Foundation*
>   *Server* we would like to be in the box
>   instead to use some other tool for
>   functions that can also be done in
>   *Team Foundation*. Will it a good choice to use *Team Foundation* instead
>   of other tool for defining *test cases*.

Once, they adopt and will generate test cases for the app.

> **Q.** We would like to attach the test
>   cases with the daily *build* and also
>   like to have log/report for monitoring
>   build progress.

This, I assume, but you can also suggest a practice which can make the aforementioned process more effective and *quick*.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TFS has a built in test runner but it is aimed at MSTest.  What test framework are you using?  TFS uses MSBuild in the background and has a template build script with hooks to allow you to customize the process.  Read up more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710(VS.80).aspx).
2. There is an TFS Web Test but I haven't looked into it much there is nothing stopping you hooking in some open source framework like Selenium into the build process

3.TFS keeps a log of all the builds done much the same as CruiseControl would.

I would recommned "Team Foundation Server 2008 in Action" as it is a very good book that explains a lot about TFS.

Comment: Thanks, Burt. Does this book cover up all about this case? If yes, then I can run off to get a copy.

Comment: It may not cover all of what you are looking for but it will give you an in depth understanding of how Team Build works so you can then extend it to fit your scenario.

Here are a couple of links to get you started:

http://vstsguidance.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Build%20Practices%20at%20a%20Glance&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=vstsguidance  
  
http://www.tfsbuild.com/

http://vstsguidance.codeplex.com/

Comment: Went to read out the book details and reviews on Amazon I encountered with another reference Inside the Microsoft® Build Engine which looks more relevant what I'm looking for. I'll look in more detail and will make my decision.

Comment: Sorry I was assuming you had previous experience with MSBuild.  If not you should really learn about it first as if you want to customise the build you will need to know it.  It will also depend on what version of TFS you are going to target 2010 is just around the corner and betas are out so may be worth waiting for it.